# Windows Batch SET with Variable Substring Length?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, substring

Take this simple example:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P phrase="Enter Word : "
SET /a rnum=%random% %%10 +1
ECHO %phrase%
ECHO %rnum%

SET rchar=%phrase:~0,%rnum%%

ECHO %rchar%
Pause
```

I just want to be able to pass that `rnum` variable to pick that as the character chosen from the left of that user entered word to that random character.

I can't seem to figure out how to pass that as a variable.

I tried with `enabledelayedexpansion` with no luck:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P Phrase="Enter Word : "
SET /a rnum=%random% %%10 +1
ECHO %phrase%
ECHO %rnum%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET rchar=!phrase:~0,%rnum%!
endlocal
ECHO %rchar%
Pause
```

So how do I pass `rnum` as a variable in this instance? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: The issue is not with your enabled delayed expansion, it is with your `endlocal`, which will undefine any variables defined or modified wiithin that delayed expansion block. The simplest way to overcome that is to replace lines `7` and `8` in your lower code with `For %%G In ("!phrase:~0,%rnum%!") Do EndLocal & Set "rchar=%%G"`

Comment: Thank you very much! That seems to work. Just one thing though the variable now includes the result in quotes as in if `phrase=1234567890` and `rnum=6` the result of `ECHO %rchar%` is `"123456"` instead of just `123456`. I did use `SET rchar=%rchar:"=%` and that seems to work but is there another way in  the code you proposed? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry HTWingNut, just a typo on my behalf, change it to `For %%G In ("!phrase:~0,%rnum%!") Do EndLocal & Set "rchar=%%~G"` instead! Also please delete the solution from your question, you should not add answers/solutions to your question, those should be added as answers in the appropriate area. Feel free to add it there yourself, you could even, given a sufficient period of time, accept your own answer too!

Comment: @Compo - Thanks. But I think your first line was correct, it gave me the result I needed. Just it includes quotes in the output, but I fixed that with `SET rchar=%rchar:"=%`

If you want to leave it as a an actual answer I'll be happy to mark it as correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple modification of your example delayed expansion code, which shows one method of maintaining your variable value beyond `endlocal`:

```sh
@ECHO OFF
SET /P "phrase=Enter Word : "
SET /A rnum = %RANDOM% %% 10 + 1
ECHO %phrase%
ECHO %rnum%
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%G IN ("!phrase:~0,%rnum%!") DO ENDLOCAL & SET "rchar=%%~G"
ECHO rchar=%rchar%
PAUSE
```

The above example should be fine, as long as the end user does not begin to input strings with problematic characters. If you wanted to make it a little more robust for such scenarios then perhaps this will help:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:AskString
Rem Get interactive string input
Set "String="
Set /P String="Enter Word : "
If Not Defined String GoTo AskString
Set String

Rem Generate a random integer 1..10
Set /A "Integer = (%RANDOM% %% 10) + 1"
Set Integer

Rem Create a substring variable using %String% and %Integer%
Echo %%SubString%% = %%String:~0,%Integer%%%
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^=^ UseBackQ %%G In ('"!String:~0,%Integer%!"') Do (
    EndLocal
    Set "SubString=%%~G"
)
Set SubString

Pause
```

Please note that the above code uses `Set Variable` to display the variable name along side its value. If your variable contains certain poison characters just using `Echo %Variable%` may not work, and you would probably be better off keeping delayed expansion enabled at that time.

Answer (score 1):

As Compo already comments, the position of your `endlocal` is the problem.

You could just move the endlocal after the `echo`

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET /P Phrase="Enter Word : "
SET /a rnum=%random% %%10 +1
ECHO !phrase!
ECHO !rnum!
SET "rchar=!phrase:~0,%rnum%!"
ECHO !rchar!
endlocal
```

Comment: Whilst that would work, if all they wanted to do was just `echo` it, there would be no real need to define `rchar` at all, i.e. `ECHO !phrase:~0,%rnum%! & endlocal`

Comment: thanks, but I want to carry it as a variable.